# settings required for multi-website in magento

Tags: apache, magento, networking, dns, webserver

I want to manage multisite-multistore in magento. Here are to domains 
1. WWW.ABC.COM
2. SECOND.XYZ.com

FYI: primary URL is www.abc.com and secondary URL id second.xyz.com which is belongs to another domain (xyz.com).

Please help me how can I manage these in magento and whats configuration are required on server.

both sites are hosted on dedicated server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Manage Stores section, add an entry for your second website. Remember the code you assigned to it. I will use "xyz" for this example.

Create your store and store views for the new website.

Backup your index.php file.

At the bottom of index.php, set the mage run code to your website code; set the run type to 'website':

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : 'xyz'; 

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'website';
```

This will run Magento as your second website. Test to make sure.

Copy this file -- and .htaccess -- to the document root of the XYZ website. Symlink all the base directories (app, js, lib, skin, media, etc.) to the ABC site.

Restore the original index.php file on the ABC site.

Set the base URLs for the XYZ site in System Config->Web.

You should be set.

This, however, is just one way to do it. See [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/navigation/multiple-website-setup) for more.